# js.coffee.erb - sync issue?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps-api-3, coffeescript, erb

I am trying to insert latitude and longitude values from a database into my google maps coffeescript.

```
jQuery ->
  initialize()

initialize = ->
  myOptions =
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(<%= @location.latitude %>, <%= @location.longitude %>)
    zoom: 12
    mapTypeControlOptions: {mapTypeIds: ["OSM", "OCM", "MQ", google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID]}
  map = new google.maps.Map $('#map_canvas')[0], myOptions
```

[...]

I get the following error message:

```
 undefined method `latitude' for nil:NilClass
   (in /Users/sg/rails-projects/geo_rails_test/app/assets/javascripts/gmap.js.coffee.erb)
```

suggesting that my Location Object

```
@location = Location.find(params[:id])
```

has not yet been instantiated at the time of parsing the js.coffee.erb file. (??)

I have tested the coffeescript with hard-coded values and @location.latitude works perfectly in my view.
Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your (Java|Coffee)Script assets will be processed and sent to the browser *before* your controller even runs. That means that `@location` won't come from your controller, it will come from whatever `self` happens to be when your `.js.coffee.erb` is converted to JavaScript. When deploying to production, the assets will (or at least should be) compiled before anything even hits your production system so `@location` has no hope of being anything useful.

You should build your data in your controller's ERB rather than the asset:

```
<!-- Somewhere in the appropriate app/views/... file... -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.global_location = { lat: <%= @location.latitude %>, lng: <%= @location.longitude %> }; 
</script>
```

and then your asset can get the data through the `this_location` global:

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(global_loc.lat, global_loc.lng)
```

Or you could try loading the location through an AJAX call.

Only use ERB in your assets for per-application constants and configuration values, don't try to use ERB in your assets for anything that will change while your application is running.

Comment: Yeah, I had thought something like this. Thanks for the info, I guess long-term AJAX is the more elegant solution.

Comment: I would put `data-coordinates="{ lat:<%= @location.latitude %>, lng:<%= @location.longitude %>]"` on #map_canvas and get it back with `$('#map_canvas').data('coordinates')`

Comment: @Guillaume86: That's a good one too, or separate `data-lat` and `data-lng` attributes depending on the situation.